# Sorting mysql varchar column with where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with column points[VARCHAR]

When I take the records with points greater than 80 and order by points in descending order. I get only numbers from 99. Actually I have points greater than 100.

Tried the option of adding +0 but strange results in ascending order,
gets data from points with 8

Answer (score 3):

Since this column is `varchar` comparisons for sorting and where clauses are done **alphabetically**, not numerically. That means '80' > '100' because '8' < '1'. You need to convert this column to an `integer`. Use `CAST(points AS INTEGER)` instead of just points.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use just make your `points` an [Integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)?

`SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`points`> 80 ORDER BY`points`DESC`

Comment: You can make it a Decimal(10,2), where 10 is how wide you want the left part of your floating point number, and 2 is the right width.

Comment: hes talking about decimal places essentially, how far left and right of the decimal do you want to save.